# vim is not using my ~/.vimrc settings and uses spaces in python code

Tags: vim, tabs

I am using **vim 8.1** on **Windows 10**. This vim came with **git bash**.

When I type a tab key, I actually get a proper TAB character, 8 wide, which is what I want.

However, if I edit a **.py** file, then instead of TABs, I get 4 spaces. Ugh. Why?

Anyways... I have my ~/.vimrc saying:

```
set tabstop=8
set ts=8
set shiftwidth=8
set gfn=Courier_New:h14:cANSI:qDRAFT
```

But why is this not used?

```
$ vi -V1
not found in 'runtimepath': "ftdetect/*.vim"
not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/start/*"
not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/start/*"
not found in 'runtimepath': "plugin/**/*.vim"
Reading viminfo file "/c/Users/abrahamstolk/.viminfo" info oldfiles
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I use `vi --version` I see that vim claims to be reading `$HOME/.vimrc` but it does not appear to do so?

```
$ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct  1 2019 05:31:13)
Included patches: 1-2104
Compiled by <alexpux@gmail.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +python/dyn        +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      -sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim81"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I/usr/include/ncursesw  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -pipe -Wl,--as-needed -o vim.exe        -lm -lelf    -lncursesw -liconv -lacl -lintl   -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
```

Comment: @matt. Awesome! `let g:python_recommended_style = 0` in my .vimrc fixes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Python world [spaces are preferred](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) so `vim` editing a Python file is configured to expand tabs.

Technically this is done this way. Installed `vim` has a huge runtime library which includes file-types plugins. [Python ftplugin](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/41a4141ecb36cd871c6e87f6fbc12fa81653b6be/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim#L118) sets [`expandtab`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27expandtab%27). The ft plugin is loaded every time `vim` detects Python file.